Unable to import nltk in Jupyter Notebook
I have a Jupyter Notebook. I installed ntlk using the following line of code:
!pip install nltk

I get the following output:
Requirement already satisfied: nltk in ./env/lib/python3.12/site-packages (3.9)
Requirement already satisfied: click in ./env/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from nltk) (8.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in ./env/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from nltk) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: regex>=2021.8.3 in ./env/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from nltk) (2024.7.24)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in ./env/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from nltk)

Now when I import nltk using
import nltk  

I get the following error:
LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/Desktop/machine-learning/env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py:84, in LazyCorpusLoader.__load(self)
     83 try:
---> 84     root = nltk.data.find(f"{self.subdir}/{zip_name}")
     85 except LookupError:

File ~/Desktop/machine-learning/env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nltk/data.py:579, in find(resource_name, paths)
    578 resource_not_found = f"\n{sep}\n{msg}\n{sep}\n"
--> 579 raise LookupError(resource_not_found)

LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource wordnet not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

What am I missing?

Are you sure it's the import causing the error and not other code in the cell using the module? You should be able to import on its own https://www.nltk.org/data.html

Thats the only cell I am trying to execute. As soon as I import nltk it falls apart.

You could try !python -m nltk.downloader all, otherwise the docs include manually installing the datasets

@OneCricketeer I typed this command in notebook but it does not do anything.

You might have to run it outside a notebook. It's supposed to open a ntlk downloader gui window

python -m nltk.downloader all
/Users/johndoe/miniconda3/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'nltk.downloader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk')

Is ~/Desktop/machine-learning/env a venv that you need to activate first?

It is an environment and it is already activated.

If it's activated, then the error shouldn't be using Users/johndoe/miniconda3/bin/python, but the path of the venv python instead... You might also want to use conda install, rather than pip install

tried conda install also but got the same issue.

It isn't going to help in this case because the base install step worked, however, you'll have a better experience in modern Jupyter if you adapt to using the modern magic install commands when running inside an active Jupyter .ipynb file. What you are doing using an exclamation point in conjunction with pip was found to cause issues in certain situations and so in 2019 the magic install commands were added to ensure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel backing the notebook is running. See here for more details.

You need to download the WordNet dataset using the NLTK downloader.
Try running this command:
import nltk

nltk.download('wordnet')

